# Trait implementation calling a function of similar name

Tags: rust, traits

Trying to abstract some algorithm where I only need `Set` operations I write

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

trait Set<T> {
    fn insert(self: &mut Self, item: T);
    fn contains(self: &Self, item: T) -> bool;
}

impl<T> Set<T> for HashSet<T> {
    fn insert(&mut self, item: T) {
        self.insert(item);
    }
    fn contains(&self, item: T) -> bool {
        self.contains(item)
    }
}

impl<T> Set<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn insert(&mut self, item: T) {
        self.push(item);
    }
    fn contains(&self, item: T) -> bool {
        self.contains(item)
    }
}
```

I get warning about recursion at compile time, while I "obviously" don't want to recurse but use the underlying implementation on the implementer.

```
function cannot return without recursing

cannot return without recursing

note: `#[warn(unconditional_recursion)]` on by default
help: a `loop` may express intention better if this is on purposerustc(unconditional_recursion)
```

I would have expected recursion to happen only if specified `(self as Set<T>).insert`

What is the idiomatic way to go around that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that `HashSet::insert` should have priority over your trait function.

But the thing is that `HashSet::insert` actually requires `T` to implement `Eq + Hash`. Since your `T` is unrestricted the `HashSet::insert` is not considered, the only `insert` available is that of the `Set` trait, and you get an unexpected recursion.

To discover this you can try compiling:

```
    fn insert(&mut self, item: T) {
        HashSet::insert(self, item);
    }
```

and get the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::cmp::Eq` is not satisfied
```

Fortunately, the Rustc people have considered this posibility of error (it happened to me, too) and have added a very helpful warning.

If you change that to:

```
impl<T: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash> Set<T> for HashSet<T> {
    fn insert(&mut self, item: T) {
        self.insert(item);
    }
}
```

then it works. (There are other unrelated errors around, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Use specialized calls:

```rust
impl<T> Set<T> for HashSet<T> where T: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash {
    fn insert(&mut self, item: T) {
        HashSet::insert(self, item);
    }
    fn contains(&self, item: T) -> bool {
        HashSet::contains(self, &item)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=975e29d6bc91e10e8bbae7f8c3ac1220)

Comment: Thanks. bulletproof and simple

Answer (score 0):

You could build a wrapper type to go around that:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

trait Set<T> {
    fn insert(self: &mut Self, item: T);
    fn contains(self: &Self, item: T) -> bool;
}

struct HashSetWrapper<T> {
    hash_set: HashSet<T>
}

impl<T> Set<T> for HashSetWrapper<T> 
where T: Eq + std::hash::Hash
{
    
    fn insert(&mut self, item: T) {
        self.hash_set.insert(item);
    }
    fn contains(&self, item: T) -> bool {
        self.hash_set.contains(&item)
    }
}
```

Note that T has to implement Eq +
Hash

Comment: thank you. I could but that's more "tagging" and it nests calls. the compiler probably optimizes it out, but tagless and static calls are better.